# XSLT Ignores some <apply-template .. > tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I am inserting a new element into an existing xml, I get my xpaths (where the element should be inserted) in an xml file, so I wrote a program that generates the XSLT script according to that input. Now whenever I am running it, it adds the elements to some xpaths and ignores the rest, I included all the namespaces that are being used, but what it's doing is that it's going to a certain hierarchy level and it doesn't go past it, at least this is what I am seeing. here is a snippet of the code for two templates one that inserts the element and the other that does not insert the element at all. Please tell me what I am doing wrong in here..

These are the templates that I can add due to the size:

```
        <xsl:copy>
            <flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
                <flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
                <message>
                    <p>r5 Designator Text is empty    </p>
                </message>
            </flag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:copy>
            <flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
                <flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
                <message>
                    <p>r7 default title is blank    </p>
                </message>
            </flag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:copy>
            <flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
                <flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
                <message>
                    <p>r7 default title is blank    </p>
                </message>
            </flag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:copy>
            <flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
                <flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
                <message>
                    <p>r5 Designator Text is empty    </p>
                </message>
            </flag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:copy>
            <flag sender="me" recipient="you" issueDateTime="02/14/2011">
                <flagSubject> Error </flagSubject>
                <message>
                    <p>r7 default title is blank    </p>
                </message>
            </flag>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't know whay it truncated the begining of the code please replace from error with this:

Comment: You have to format your code (html characters were escaped), look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @tigris: The `<xsl:stylesheet>` is missing -- maybe other things, too. Please, provide a complete stylesheet.

Comment: @tigris: I have answered your question, explaining the most likely reason for the problem. And +1 for your effort.

Comment: @manji: thank you a lot for editing the question.. Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I added the XML sample along with all the template tags used.. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. the template tags have not been added, I don't have enough room to add them.. I tried to post them as answer but I don't have enough reputations!

Comment: @tigris: I notice that your sample XML uses the namespace prefix `default:` (not to be confused with the default namespace), but does not declare it.

Comment: OK.. so I was able to add some templates but that is the maximum that I can add!!

Comment: @tigris: you can probably solve the problem of running out of space, by cutting your XML sample way down. Just include the part that you believe should be matched by the first and second templates, and a little context (including all ancestors). You can use "..." to show where you left stuff out, if necessary.

Comment: OK.. It's solved, it was overriding the element as Dimitre suggested.. Thank you ALL for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here is a snippet of the code for two
>   templates one that inserts the element
>   and the other that does not insert the
>   element at all. Please tell me what I
>   am doing wrong in here..

In the provided code there are two templates each overriding the identity rule/template for particular elements.

The fact that the first template "does not insert the element at all" means that there isn't any node that matches the match-pattern of this template.

If you provide the source XML document many people will show you that there isn't any such element in this XML document.

In case there are actually more templates (which you haven't shown), then another possible reason is that another template that also matches such elements was chosen due to higher priority -- and this other template probably doesn't do anything that would produce output.

The second template, in contrast, obviously matches element(s) from the source XML document and it does what it is intended to do.

**Summary**: The most likely problem with the first template is that it doesn't match any node in the XML document.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, Thanks a lot for the answer. There are elements that matches the template, the input xpaths were generated based on the input xml file. The templates are unique, there are no templates that contains the same XPATH but they might contain partially similar path for example one might contain /root/element and the other one contain /root/element/subelement will this effect anything?

Comment: @tigris: You'll get your answer immediately after you post a sample XML.

Comment: Posted at the bottom of the question.. Thanks :)

Comment: I also added all the template tags used

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. the template tags have not been added, I don't have enough room to add them.. I tried to post them as answer but I don't have enough reputations!

Comment: OK.. so I was able to add some templates but that is the maximum that I can add!!

Comment: OK.. It's solved, it was overriding the element as Dimitre suggested.. Thank you ALL for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I found at least four namespace prefixes in your so-called XML that haven't been declared. At that point I gave up. This tells me two things: (a) the XML you posted is not the XML you are running against, and (b) you haven't understood that getting namespaces wrong is the most likely reason for XPath expressions (or XSLT match patterns) to fail to select anything.

Comment: Yes Micheal.. I got it to work, It didn't get all the namespaces when I pasted it. The issue was I am trying to insert repeatable elements to the same node specified by the xpath so it was overriding earlier inserted elements with the last one. Thanks for your effort, appreciate it :)